# Apache Spark streaming vs Spring XD Streams

Tags: apache-spark, spring-xd

I am looking for use cases where Apache Spark streaming will be apt and situations where Spring XD streams will best fit.

Is there a overlap of technologies here? Has someone come across a situation where both are being used?

Answer (score 0):

Spring XD works great when you don't want to do any coding and work with streams coming to and from RabbitMQ, Gemfire, JDBC, HDFS, Redis, MongoDB.

Comment: It is also extensible... you can do coding :-) ! https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/wiki/Creating-a-Processor-Module

Answer (score 0):

Spring XD provides integration with Spark streaming to get the best out of both.
You can refer to the documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#spark-streaming)

Comment: There is a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32624037/spark-cluster-spring-xd